# Why does git clone give: Server Connection Error Invalid response: 404 Not Found?

Tags: python, git, anaconda, clone, jupyter-lab

When I try to open the file after cloning a repository on Github, I get the following error:

> **Server Connection Error
>   Invalid response: 404 Not Found**

Even though it seems to successfully clone it:

```
!git clone https://github.com/neheller/kits19.git
```

Gives:

```
Cloning into 'kits19'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 954, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (954/954), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (124/124), done.
remote: Total 991 (delta 433), reused 927 (delta 408), pack-reused 37
Receiving objects: 100% (991/991), 29.70 MiB | 2.34 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (451/451), done.
```

I am using Jupiter Lab via Anaconda.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: I don't know where you're seeing the error message, or what result you expect. The result of running `git clone ...` is that a directory named `kits19` is created in the current directory (probably `%userprofile%`). Check if it's there?

Comment: Can you include more details on the URL you are trying to access that is causing the 404?

Comment: I am trying to access the directory named `kits19` which is in my current directory. When I subsequently open de directory `data` I get the previously mentioned error.
@NadavS